# Visual Studio Code no comenta como deberia el HTML con atajo de teclado

Tags: html5

Al usar mi atajo de teclado para comentar codigo en Visual Studio Code para html me lo pone de la siguiente manera

`{# Empieza el modal #}`

En vez de

`<!-- Empieza el modal -->`

Alguien sabe a que se puede deber? Gracias

Comment: haz investigado almenos?...

Comment: VSCode intenta detectar automaticamente el lenguaje y puede que eso este fallando. Cerca de la esquina inferior derecha tenes para seleccionar el modo de lenguaje.

Comment: Lo unico que tuve que hacer fue googlear, intenta buscar por tu cuenta antes de hacer una pregunta y cuando estes atascado, ahi preguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que estas usando correctamente las combinacioes de tecla. Las que uso para comentar código son las teclas shift + alt + A